# The view posts.views.create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

having problem with my posts.view page 
[image: code]
this is  my views page but the error still keeps on coming that not httpresponse

Comment: You haven't returned anything when the request method is `GET`.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow
It be good if next time you post code instead link to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #   Your code here

    return render(request, 'posts/home.html')


def home(request):
```